# Display arraylist based on another class?

Tags: java, arrays, list

so I've written an array list that should display a name and an age of a person. I have created a "Data" class with age and name, as show below:

```
public class Data 
{
private String name;
private int age;
Data(String n,int a)
{
    name = n;
    age = a;
}
public String GetName()
{
    return(name);
}
public void SetName(String n)
{
    name = n;
}
public int GetAge()
{
    return(age);
}
public void SetAge(int a)
{
    age = a;
}

public void Print()
{
    System.out.print(("("+GetName()));
    System.out.print(",");
    System.out.print(GetAge());
    System.out.print(") ");
}
}
```

I then have another class with the array list in it:

```
public class nameagelist {

public static void main(String args[])

{
    ArrayList<Data> array_list = new ArrayList<Data>();
    array_list.add(new Data("Zoe", 24));
    array_list.add(new Data("Fred", 31));
    array_list.add(new Data("Iqbal", 78));
}   

private static void PrintDataArray(ArrayList<Data> array) 
{
    for(int i=0;i<array.size();++i)
    {
        array.get(i).Print();
    }   
}
}
```

Can't work out why this wont display anything, think I may have done something wrong regarding adding things to the array but not sure! -_- Thanks!

Comment: You need to invoke `PrintDataArray` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to call the PrintDataArray method?

```
    public class nameagelist {
        public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Data> array_list = new ArrayList<Data>();
        array_list.add(new Data("Zoe", 24));
        array_list.add(new Data("Fred", 31));
        array_list.add(new Data("Iqbal", 78));
        PrintDataArray(array_list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling your PrintDataArray and passing your arraylist, so after your last array_list.add....

you should call PrintDataArray(array_list) with array_list as a parameter